# keywindow is not working in ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];) iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, keywindow

I am using below code to display a window over movie player controller:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];
```

Its working fine in iOS 5 but it stopped working in iOS 6. Even window is not displaying in iOS 6. So please can you suggest me the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` to your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method and you can use this code

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:view];
```

to your

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

method in your ViewController

Comment: Defining the UIWindow in the viewDidAppear seemed to work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Where I write this code? Before add the subview? if I write makekeyvisible in window then it shows error for window. and if I write appdelegate.window then it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it after "appdidFinishLaunching:" finished!  May solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] // available only on main thread